# How does one compute $\tan^{-1}\left [ \frac{\cos\left ( 2t \right )}{\sin\left ( 2t \right )} \right ]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How does one compute: $$\tan^{-1}\left [ \frac{\cos\left ( 2t \right )}{\sin\left ( 2t \right )} \right ]$$

I came across this in a text and I cannot figure out how the author arrive at the solution $2t + \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Which text did you find this in?  Have you tried?  If yes, please show some of the workings you came up with.

Comment: A text in chaos theory. Admittedly, simple trig stuffs from high school can be hard to recall.

Comment: Mathematicing  You might want to revisit the question and its answers, one of which is incorrect.

Comment: @amWhy Haven't the below poster rectified the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Attention: This answer was corrected, thanks for [Rory Daulton](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/161807/rory-daulton)'s heads up!**

We know that:

$$\frac{\cos(2t)}{\sin(2t)}=\cot(2t)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2t\right)=-\tan\left(2t-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

And also that:

$$\tan^{-1}(\tan(x))=x$$

So, the correct answer should be:

$$\frac{\pi}{2}-2t$$

Sorry for my previous mistaken anwser! For further info, refer to Rory's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2359650)

Comment: That equality from cotangent to tangent is not true, almost-always. It becomes true if you put a minus sign in front of either the cotangent or the tangent. The OP's stated solution is not correct. Try graphing the original and the final expressions to see this.

Comment: I agree, @Rory.  This is a very careless answer, and also, it is incorrect.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thank you very much for the heads up! I'm going to add a correction to it right now! I had the $\cot(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$ on my mind, but I was completely induced by the OP's suggested answer.

Comment: actually, the correct answer is $\dfrac{\pi}{2} - 2t \pmod \pi$

Answer (score 2):

The author's solution is incorrect. Perhaps you typed the question or the answer wrongly here?

$$\begin{align}
\tan^{-1}\left[\frac{\cos(2t)}{\sin(2t)}\right]
  & = \tan^{-1}\left[\cot(2t)\right] \\
  & = \tan^{-1}\left[\tan\left(\frac{\pi}2 -2t\right)\right] \\
  & = \frac{\pi}2 -2t \\
\end{align}$$

That last equation is true only if $-\frac{\pi}2 \le \frac{\pi}2 -2t \le \frac{\pi}2$
--i.e. for $0\le t\le \frac{\pi}2$. That limitation may be true in the context of the problem in your book. But your given "solution" is wrong.

Here is a graph showing the equality and where it is true--the tick marks on the x-axis are at multiples of pi over 2.

[image]